# TensorFlow, Keras: Test Image Larger Than Training Images

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a network to detect "bubbles" in 14x14 pixel grayscale images. I trained the network with images that contained bubbles and images that did not contain bubbles. The network works well.

Now, I have a big image with a lot of bubbles (I generated the training data from this big image)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLO0V.png).

I want the network to scan the big image using a 14x14 kernel to detect the locations of the bubbles. How can I do that?

Below is my network:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(14, 14)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect the position of bubbles with the architecture you are using. You would have to adapt your case to an algorithm like YOLO: https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088. Your output would then contain a unit indicating the presence or absence of a bubble in a particular region, and a set of units defining the coordinates of the bubbles.

Comment: It seems that yolo is exactly what i need! thanks! But instead of marking the object, i would like to get the Center Position of them. I`m sure there is so editing of yolo possible to get the Center Position.